# If port 80 is closed could we forward it to pot 8080 to retrieve apache web-server?

Tags: apache, port

My node's port number 80 is closed but its port number 8080 is accessible.

I am able to view apache web-server on port 8080 but not on port 80, since port 80 is closed and due to some firewall issues it cannot open.

- http://< site >:8080/    works!
- http://< site >        does not work.

People know our site without `:8080`.

So if someone enters "http://< site >" is it possible to forward them to `<site>:8080`?

I tried port forwarding(https://askubuntu.com/a/579540/660555), but since port number 80 was closed, it did not fixed the problem :(

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: Couldn't you configure your webserver to listen on 80? Don't you have admin access? What do you mean by port 80 is closed?

Comment: I am using my school's network and some security issues port 80 is closed via firewall. @Jean-Baptiste Yunès

Comment: Then if 80 is unreachable, you can't do anything...